# Xamarin - Binding Command to property of object inside User Control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have began learning XAML a few days ago and I have a trouble with wrapping my head around this problem.

In Xamarin Forms, I want to create a user control which will contain a label and a button and be able to bind a command to usercontrol in XAML from another page which uses my user control.

I am currently getting exception:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 8:24. Cannot assign property "Test1": Property does not exists, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property'

Here is a dumbed down version of it I am currently trying to get to work.

My Custom Control XAML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="App3.Controls.Control1">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Command="{Binding Test1}" Text="Test"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Control using my Custom Control XAML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App3"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:App3.Controls"
             x:Class="App3.MainPage">

    <controls:Control1 Test1="{Binding Test2}" />
</ContentPage>
```

My Custom Control Codebehind

```cs
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App3.Controls
{
    public partial class Control1 : ContentView
    {

        private static readonly BindableProperty controlProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Test1", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Control1), null);

        public Control1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ICommand Test1
        {
            get
            {
                return (ICommand)GetValue(controlProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(controlProperty, value);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

View Model of page using Custom Control

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App3
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            this.Test2 = new Command(test);
        }

        public void test()
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("it works", "it works", "it works");
        }

        public ICommand Test2
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a few naming convention to follow if you want your BindableProperty detected, and bindable, from Xaml:

> When you create the identifier field, name this field by the name of the property as you registered it, plus the suffix Property. This field is your identifier for the dependency property, and it will be used later as an input for the SetValue and GetValue calls you will make in the wrappers, by any other code access to the property by your own code, by any external code access you allow, by the property system, and potentially by XAML processors.

and

> Define a DependencyProperty identifier as a public static readonly field on the owner type.

(this is the documentation for DependencyProperty, but it applies to BindableProperties quite well in this case. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can fix your code by replacing

```
private static readonly BindableProperty controlProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Test1", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Control1), null);

public ICommand Test1
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(controlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(controlProperty, value); }
}
```

by

```
public static readonly BindableProperty Test1Property = BindableProperty.Create("Test1", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Control1), null);


public ICommand Test1
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(Test1Property); }
    set { SetValue(Test1Property, value); }
}
```

That should prevent the property detection issue.

to get your full stuff working, the Button command binding should have it's source set to the control itself, and you should set your `MainPageViewModel` as `BindingContext` for `MainPage`.

Comment: Why is it required that the BindableProperty is called `Test1Property` and not anything arbitrary? Initial assignment `AnyOtherNameProperty="Some Value"` worked for me well, but `AnyOtherNameProperty="{Binding MyValue}` did not until I followed your advice. Why the difference?

Comment: Note that this won't work on its own, the command will not be executed until you do what Pawel suggests...

Answer (score 7):

Thank you very much both of you, i have talked offline with Krzysztof, and after all those changes, one thing is left to make it working.

Now when you click a button in custom control (Control1) binded command will not be called, the command saved in the binding is null, but even if you notify the view to get fresh command from bindablecontext it will not work because it will not found the proper property, because we dont have specified bindablecontext so the framework will search our property somewhere else (in parent object). Dont try to set bindablecontext of custom control to this, it will brake the binding ability to this control (you will not be able to bind properly to those dependency properties).

In this situation the easiest way to solve it is to set proper binding source in xaml.
Set the name of your content view and specify the binding source in binding all bindings (Here is only one).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"   
x:Class="App3.Controls.Control1"
x:Name="MySpecifiedName">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Command="{Binding Test1, Source={x:Reference MySpecifiedName}}" Text="Test"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

I have wasted few hours on digging how to fix it so, i am writing here to save others developers which are facing those problems, time.