# How to differentiate click on a customcontrol

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good afternoon, I have a customcontrol, which has two buttons, I would like to know if it is possible for me to differentiate the individual click from each one in the implementation.but until then, the click only works on the stackLayout, and the buttons are not firing the command

-my HeaderPage.xaml

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="10*, 80*, 10*">
        <ImageButton Source="back" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" BackgroundColor="LightSkyBlue"/>
        
        <Label Text="Folha de Pagamento" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightCoral"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

        <ImageButton Source="more" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="40" BackgroundColor="LightSkyBlue"
                     Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentView.Content>
```

-HeaderPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class HeaderPage : ContentView
{
    public event EventHandler Clicked;
    public HeaderPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CriarComando();
    }

    private void CriarComando()
    {
        this.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(() =>
            {
                //if (frame.IsVisible)
                //{
                Clicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

                if (Command != null)
                {
                    if (Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter))
                        Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
                }
                //}
            })
        });
    }

    #region Command
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create
        (
            propertyName: "Command",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(HeaderPage),
            null
        );

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region CommandParameter
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create
        (
            propertyName: "CommandParameter",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(HeaderPage),
            null
        );

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

-control implementation

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:HeaderPage Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="1"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: each button has it's own clicked/command behavior.  Why are you adding a TapGesture to the entire control if you want to recognize each Button?

Comment: I confess that I don't know how to proceed to do it correctly, could you help me please?

Comment: A related question with similar requirements and issue, see question and answer to get idea about how you can modify your control: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753496/xamarin-binding-command-to-property-of-object-inside-user-control

Comment: The command you passed to the control where are you assigning it in header xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a customcontrol, which has two buttons, I would like to know if it is possible for me to differentiate the individual click from each one in the implementation.

You mean that you create custom control, there are two imageButton, firing the different method when click two imagebutton, am I right?

If yes, please take a look the following code:

Customcontrol:

```
 <ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="button1"
            Command="{Binding ImageButton1}"
            HeightRequest="40"
            Source="check.png"
            WidthRequest="100" />
        <Label Text="test" />
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="button2"
            Command="{Binding ImageButton2}"
            HeightRequest="40"
            Source="icaon.png"
            WidthRequest="100" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Then create two BindableProperty Command for binding:

```
public partial class View1 : ContentView
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageButton1Property = BindableProperty.Create("ImageButton1", typeof(ICommand), typeof(View1), null,propertyChanged:ImageButton1Propertychanged
        );

    private static void ImageButton1Propertychanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (View1)bindable;
        control.button1.Command = (System.Windows.Input.ICommand)newValue;
    }

    public ICommand ImageButton1
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ImageButton1Property); }
        set { SetValue(ImageButton1Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageButton2Property = BindableProperty.Create("ImageButton2", typeof(ICommand), typeof(View1), null,propertyChanged:ImageButton2Propertychanged);

    private static void ImageButton2Propertychanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (View1)bindable;
        control.button2.Command = (System.Windows.Input.ICommand)newValue;
    }

    public ICommand ImageButton2
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ImageButton2Property); }
        set { SetValue(ImageButton2Property, value); }
    }
    public View1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Finally, using this custom control in Page.

```
 <customcontrol:View1 ImageButton1="{Binding image1}" ImageButton2="{Binding image2}" />

 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
   
    public Command image1 { get; set; }

    public Command image2 { get; set; }
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       
        image1 = new Command(imagebutton1);
        image2 = new Command(imagebutton2);
        

        this.BindingContext = this;

       
    }
    private void imagebutton1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the imagebutton1 click");
    }
    private void imagebutton2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the imagebutton2 click");
    }
```

Comment: @Gabriel Ribeiro Rossi  If my reply have solved your problem, please remember to mark it as answer, it is beneficial to others who face the same problem, thanks.